# Is there a way to encourage people to tag the render engine they are using?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have noticed that one of the most common first comments on a question is something like “What render engine are you using?”.  My question is simply this, is there anyway to remind people to put the render engine in the tags?

Some kind of note like “Please be sure that if your question has anything to do with rendering (materials, rendering, etc.) that you include in the tags what render engine you are using.”  I myself have just forgotten to specify render engine occasionally since I always use cycles.  So I think this would be beneficial to everyone, askers and answerers, new and experienced users.

Is it possible to implement something like [Greg Zaal's Idea](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/526/is-there-a-way-to-encourage-people-to-tag-the-render-engine-they-are-using#comment2995_526), so users would get a message like "Please make sure you tag what render engine your are using." if they use the [rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering) or [materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) or other similar tags?

Comment: This would be a great notice to have on the "ask a question" page.. +1

Comment: I agree, another one would be to attach photos or a .blend. Seems like I am constantly asking for those.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way of forcing them to choose the render engine if they have added the *rendering* tag?

Comment: @GregZaal or the [tag:materials] tag.